# Can this code be factorized with no runtime impact?

Tags: c++, refactoring

I had those two member functions of `MyClass`:

```
Result MyClass::func1( const CommonParam& commonParam1, const CommonParam& commonParam2, const CommonParam& commonParam3, const ExtraParam1& extraParam1 )
{
    Result result;
    // prolog code, common to all, using commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3
    doSomething( 1, commonParam1, commonParam2, extraParam1 );
    // epilog code, common to all, using commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3
    return result;
}

Result MyClass::func2( const CommonParam& commonParam1, const CommonParam& commonParam2, const CommonParam& commonParam3, const ExtraParam2& extraParam2, const ExtraParam3& extraParam3 )
{
    Result result;
    // prolog code, common to all, using commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3
    doSomething( 1, commonParam1, commonParam2, extraParam2, extraParam3 );
    // epilog code, common to all, using commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3
    return result;
}
```

I need to factorize this to avoid duplication of prolog/epilog code which are exactly the same for both function (is modifies MyClass attributes, prolog creates variables used by epilog...stuff like that). The only difference is that a different version of `MyClass::doSomething` is called (with different parameters). As `doSomething` is called with a different set of parameters, I used this approach for factorization using template and introducing a helper class:

```
class helper1
{
public:
    helper1( const ExtraParam1& extraParam1 ) : extraParam1(extraParam1) {}
    inline bool compute( MyClass& parent, const CommonParam& commonParam1, const CommonParam& commonParam2 ) const
    {
        return parent.doSomething( 1, commonParam1, commonParam2, extraParam1 );
    }

private:
    const ExtraParam1& extraParam1;
};

class helper2
{
public:
    helper2( const ExtraParam2& extraParam2, const ExtraParam3& extraParam3 ) : extraParam2(extraParam2), extraParam3(extraParam3) {}
    inline bool compute( MyClass& parent, const CommonParam& commonParam1, const CommonParam& commonParam2 ) const
    {
        return parent.doSomething( 1, commonParam1, commonParam2, extraParam2, extraParam3 );
    }

private:
    const ExtraParam2& extraParam2;
    const ExtraParam3& extraParam3;
};

template<typename Helper>
inline Result funcT( MyClass& parent,
                     const CommonParam& commonParam1, 
                     const CommonParam& commonParam2, 
                     const CommonParam& commonParam3,
                     const Helper& helper )
{
    // this function is a friend of MyClass, so prolog/epilog can use any private class attribute

    Result result;
    // prolog code, common to all, using commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3
    helper.compute( parent, commonParam1, commonParam2 );
    // epilog code, common to all, using commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3
    return result;
}

Result MyClass::func1( const CommonParam& commonParam1, const CommonParam& commonParam2, const CommonParam& commonParam3, const ExtraParam1& extraParam1 )
{
    return funcT( *this, commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3, helper1( *this, extraParam1) );
}

Result MyClass::func2( const CommonParam& commonParam1, const CommonParam& commonParam2, const CommonParam& commonParam3, const ExtraParam2& extraParam2, const ExtraParam3& extraParam3 )
{
    return funcT( *this, commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3, helper2( *this, extraParam2, extraParam3 ) );
}
```

Those functions are called billions of times by our algorithm, so the refactoring must have the lowest runtime impact.

`compute` is `inline` and everything is passed by reference and I used template rather than virtual table to minimize runtime impact. However, I guess this has an impact at runtime (at least we create `helper1`, `helper2` objects).

Does my refactoring have a runtime impact that compiler won't remove?
If yes, could someone propose a refactoring with lower runtime impact?

Answer (score 2):

> Does my refactoring have a runtime impact that compiler won't remove? If yes, could someone propose a refactoring with lower runtime impact?

The only way to be sure that you're not introducing overhead **is measuring**. Profile your code before/after refactoring and **check the generated assembly**.

---

As an addendum, here's a slightly simpler way of refactoring your code that should still be easy for the compiler to inline. Instead of storing references to the extra parameters, they are perfectly-forwarded to a generic callable object:

```
template <typename TF, typename... TExtraParams>
Result MyClass::generic_func( const TF& doSomething, const CommonParam& commonParam1, const CommonParam& commonParam2, const CommonParam& commonParam3, const TExtraParams&&... extraParams )
{
    Result result;
    // prolog code, common to all, using commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3
    doSomething( 1, commonParam1, commonParam2, std::forward<TExtraParams>(extraParams)... );
    // epilog code, common to all, using commonParam1, commonParam2, commonParam3
    return result;
}
```

With your current design, it can be used as follows:

```
generic_func([](
    const CommonParam& a, const CommonParam& b, const CommonParam& c, 
    const ExtraParam& extra0
)
{
    // ... will be called between prolog and epilog
}, my_a, my_b, my_c, extra0);
```